# IdentityServer4 API Resource & Spring Framework

Tags: spring, rest, identityserver4

I have configured an IdentityServer4 server to protect my API resources.

I have linked my .NET Core based API resource to the Identity Server but I need to know how to link a Java-based API resource.

I have a REST API based on Spring Framework and I need to configure it in a way it validates incoming JWT tokens with the Identity Server.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my own question.

I use Gradle so I added the following line to my build.gradle file:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'
```

Then is my **application.properties** file I added the following:

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=<API_RESOURCE_ID>
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=<API_RESOURCE_SECRET>
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=<TOKEN_ENDPOINT>
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=<AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT>
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=<USERINFO_ENDPOINT>
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=<INTROSPECT_ENDPOINT>
security.oauth2.resource.prefer-token-info=true

logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Then I needed to implement **ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter** interface.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"))
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
     resources.resourceId(<API_RESOURCE_ID>);
}
```

And finally adding **@EnableOAuth2Sso** to my **Application.java** file.

Comment: Thx @Alex!
I had the exacle same problem and this post save me much time...